# Read user given file character by character in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which is kind of unformatted, I want to place a new-line after every 100th character and remove any other new lines in it so that file may look with consistent width and readable

This code snippet helps read all the lines

```
 while read LINE
        do
                len=${#LINE}
                echo "Line length is : $len"
        done < $file
```

but how do i do same for characters

Idea is to have something like this : (*just an example, it may have syntax errors, not implemented yet*)

```
 while read ch  #read character
  do
         chcount++ # increment character count

    if [ "$chcount" -eq "100" && "$ch"!="\n" ] #if 100th character and is not a new line
    then
        echo -e "\n" #echo new line
    elif [ "$ch"=="\n" ]  #if character is not 100th but new line
        then
        ch=" " $replace it with space
     fi
  done < $file
```

I am learning `bash`, so please go easy!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to place a new-line after every 100th character and remove any
>   other new lines in it so that file may look with consistent width and
>   readable

Unless you have a good reason to write a script, go ahead but you don't need one.

Remove the newline from the input and fold it.  Saying:

```
tr -d '\n' < inputfile | fold -w 100
```

should achieve the desired result.

Comment: @NoobEditor I'll defer that for lack of time right now.  That said, reinventing the wheel rarely sounds convincing.

Comment: lemme know when you can....patience is my virtue....meanwhile if i get something online, would delete the question! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I'll leave you with a hint meanwhile: `read` would read a line of input (which wouldn't contain a newline).

Comment: sorry for accepting this answer so late! _/\\_

Answer (score 7):

`bash` adds a `-n` flag to the standard `read` command to specify a number of characters to read, rather than a full line:

```
while read -n1 c; do
    echo "$c"
done < $file
```

Comment: `n` i understand, whats `1` in `n1`?? also, does it reads `whites-paces` and `new-line`??

Comment: `-n` takes a mandatory argument; `-n2` would read two characters at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the function below in any of the following ways:

```
line_length=100
wrap $line_length <<< "$string"
wrap $line_length < file_name
wrap $line_length < <(command)
command | wrap $line_length
```

The function reads the input line by line (more efficiently than by character) which essentially eliminates the existing newlines (which are replaced by spaces). The remainder of the previous line is prefixed to the current one and the result is split at the desired line length. The remainder after the split is kept for the next iteration. If the output buffer is full, it is output and cleared otherwise it's kept for the next iteration so more can be added. Once the input has been consumed, there may be additional text in the remainder. The function is called recursively until that is also consumed and output.

```
wrap () { 
    local remainder rest part out_buffer line len=$1
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        line="$remainder$line "
        (( part = $len - ${#out_buffer} ))
        out_buffer+=${line::$part}
        remainder=${line:$part}
        if (( ${#out_buffer} >= $len ))
        then
            printf '%s\n' "$out_buffer"
            out_buffer=
        fi
    done
    rest=$remainder
    while [[ $rest ]]
    do
        wrap $len <<< "$rest"
    done
    if [[ $out_buffer ]]
    then
        printf '%s\n' "$out_buffer"
        out_buffer=
    fi
}
```

Comment: going through your answer...now i realise i dont understand `bash-scripting` at all!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
w=~/testFile.txt
chcount=0
while read -r word ; do
        len=${#word}
        for (( i = 0 ; i <= $len - 1 ; ++i )) ; do
                let chcount+=1
                if [ $chcount -eq 100 ] ; then
                        printf "\n${word:$i:1}"
                        let chcount=0
                else
                        printf "${word:$i:1}"
                fi
        done
done < $w
```

Are you looking for something like this?